# Can't decode JSON value in PHP

Tags: php, json, decode, decoding

I found no solution for this.

I have an API witch give me JSON resposne,

http://api.vajehyab.com/v2/public/?q=%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85&developer=stackoverflow

which is something like this,

> {"search":{"q":"\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645","code":200},"data":{"title":"\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645","pronunciation":"","text":"(\u0633\u064e) [ \u0639 . ] (\u0645\u0635 \u0644 .) 1 - \u062f\u0631\u0648\u062f \u06af\u0641\u062a\u0646 . 2 -  \u0628\u06cc \u06af\u0632\u0646\u062f \u0634\u062f\u0646 . 3 - \u06af\u0631\u062f\u0646 \u0646\u0647\u0627\u062f\u0646 .  \u061b ~ \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u06a9 \u062f\u0631\u0648\u062f \u0628\u0631 \u062a\u0648 \u0628\u0627\u062f.  \u061b ~ \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u06a9\u0645  \u062f\u0631\u0648\u062f \u0628\u0631 \u0634\u0645\u0627. ","source":"\u0641\u0631\u0647\u0646\u06af \u0641\u0627\u0631\u0633\u06cc \u0645\u0639\u06cc\u0646 | \u0648\u0627\u0698\u0647 \u06cc\u0627\u0628","permalink":"?q=%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85"},"error":{"message":"","reason":""},"ads":{"text":"","url":""}}

It doesn't seem to have problem ,I can decode it in other tools but PHP, I can't decode it in PHP

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.vajehyab.com/v2/public/?q='.urlencode('سلام').'&developer=stackoverflow');
var_dump(json_decode($json)); // null
```

I hope somebody could help me with this, 
thank you...

Comment: use json_last_error(). and check the error code.

Comment: I did as @Stanimir said, and it's a `- Syntax error, malformed JSON`,

Comment: Works for me on PHP 5.5.21, maybe a question of PHP version then.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from php docs http://php.net/manual/bg/function.json-last-error.php
Run this code and let us know if you receive any errors.

```
json_decode($string);

switch(json_last_error())
{
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hi, it's `- Syntax error, malformed JSON`, :|
What should I do now ? :-/

Answer (score 2):

EDIT2: In PHP 5.3+ this seems to work too:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.vajehyab.com/v2/public/?q='.urlencode('سلام').'&developer=stackoverflow');

$unescaped = json_encode(preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u(\w{4})/', function ($matches) {
    return html_entity_decode('&#x' . $matches[1] . ';', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
}, $json));
var_dump($unescaped);
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933162/2433843

EDIT3: wrapped the `preg_replace_callback` in `json_encode`

Comment: No, `json_decode` still return null ! `jsonlint` validate both of them but PHP say it's not :|

Comment: Sorry @EmadGhasemi, try this:  
    `$unescaped = json_encode(preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u(\w{4})/', function ($matches) {
     return html_entity_decode('&#x' . $matches[1] . ';', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
 }, $json));`

Comment: You're right, it feels kind of hacky, but it seems it is interpreted as if it was never properly encoded in the first place (I know, it does work in JS Linters). Perhaps it's better to solve it server-side, but perhaps it's a flaw in the PHP json implementation. This seems to work for me though, but I understand if it is too dirty to implement. I'm interested to see the clean solution!

Comment: It seems that they are using php 5.5.9, and somebody in the comments mentioned it worked with no problem in 5.5.21. Maybe something is going wrong with `json_encode` in 5.5.x :-/

Comment: Ok. Did you try above code? Sorry if it doesn't work; here it works on PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6 (local development environment)

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this.

```
echo htmlentities((string)$results);
```

Also reffer [Problem with json_decode PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324645/problem-with-json-decode-php)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from `file_get_contents` function. `json_decode` works fine when input is string. Below code run correctly.

```
$json = '{"search":{"q":"\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645","code":200},"data":{"title":"\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645","pronunciation":"","text":"(\u0633\u064e) [ \u0639 . ] (\u0645\u0635 \u0644 .) 1 - \u062f\u0631\u0648\u062f \u06af\u0641\u062a\u0646 . 2 - \u0628\u06cc \u06af\u0632\u0646\u062f \u0634\u062f\u0646 . 3 - \u06af\u0631\u062f\u0646 \u0646\u0647\u0627\u062f\u0646 . \u061b ~ \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u06a9 \u062f\u0631\u0648\u062f \u0628\u0631 \u062a\u0648 \u0628\u0627\u062f. \u061b ~ \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u06a9\u0645 \u062f\u0631\u0648\u062f \u0628\u0631 \u0634\u0645\u0627. ","source":"\u0641\u0631\u0647\u0646\u06af \u0641\u0627\u0631\u0633\u06cc \u0645\u0639\u06cc\u0646 | \u0648\u0627\u0698\u0647 \u06cc\u0627\u0628","permalink":"?q=%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85"},"error":{"message":"","reason":""},"ads":{"text":"","url":""}}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Comment: I tried it with CURL function too, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please encode your data to utf8 format before encoding it through json_encode() php function. I hope , it helps. [utf8_encode()]